# Node.js, express if statment running even when the condition is false

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, if-statement

I am trying to check whether the signed in user is admin or not. User data is stored in a format like this:

```
[
  {
    "isAdmin": "true",
    "_id": "60c6df22f25d381e78ab5f31",
    "name": "Admin",
    "email": "admn@xyz.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$dPF0rtehOYXv5aLkmxXgw.99horXCuzbQgvu5ywRaa5C73xQJpaG6",
    "__v": 0,
    "createdAt": "2021-06-14T04:46:26.769Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-06-14T04:46:26.769Z"
  },
  {
    "isAdmin": "false",
    "_id": "60c6df22f25d381e78ab5f32",
    "name": "Messi",
    "email": "messi@xyz.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$Lkhuz2///oLfrCRMSYoHoeS3QHUCNQDH3OyiN6LyveogGfzldSBDC",
    "__v": 0,
    "createdAt": "2021-06-14T04:46:26.770Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-06-20T03:45:44.533Z"
  },
]
```

when the user enter its credentials I am passing adminMiddleware to check wheather `isAdmin` is false or true. But when I tested it in [thunder client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rangav.vscode-thunder-client) I got user data no matter who's bearer token I passed (Admin or normal users).

here is the source code:

**adminMiddleware.js**

```
const admin = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log("Name:", req.user.name);
    console.log("isAdmin:", req.user.isAdmin);
    if (req.user && req.user.isAdmin) {
      next();
    } else {
      const error = new Error("Not Authorized As An Admin");
      error.status = 401;
      next(error);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

module.exports = admin;
```

**userRoutes.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const {
  registerUser,
  getUsers,
} = require("../controllers/userController");
const protect = require("../middleware/authMiddleware");
const admin = require("../middleware/adminMiddleware");
const router = express.Router();

router.route("/").post(registerUser).get(protect, admin, getUsers);
module.exports = router;
```

I console logged the **isAdmin** value for both admin and normal user by there Bearer Token respectively and got:

when **isAdmin=false**
[image]

when **isAdmin=true**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, it seems that your `isAdmin` attribute has a string value.
In that case, the condition `req.user.isAdmin` will always be true.

Here is an example:

```js
const user1 = {isAdmin: "true", name: "messi"}
const user2 = {isAdmin: "true", name: "messi"}

if(user1.isAdmin) {
  console.log(typeof user1.isAdmin);
  console.log("User 1 is admin");
}

if(user2.isAdmin) {
  console.log(typeof user2.isAdmin);
  console.log("User 2 is admin");
}
```

So in this case the correct way to verify the attribute would be `req.user.isAdmin === 'true'`

or

You could simply update the attribute to a boolean value using `isAdmin: true` in your user attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`req.user.isAdmin` resolves as string, so, `"false"` is a truty value: `"false" ? true : false`.

You should change your check to `req.user && req.user.isAdmin === 'true'`

Answer (score 1):

Hi as I read all stuff I found that you just checked "isAdmin" key rather then its value. Try below

```
if (req.user && req.user.isAdmin==="true") {
      next();
    } else {
      const error = new Error("Not Authorized As An Admin");
      error.status = 401;
      next(error);
    }
```